# Age Appropriate Chores for 6 Year Old

Tags: chores

Looking for a suggestion on age appropriate chores for a 6 year old to help out around the house?

Comment: See also https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/968/316

Answer (score 3):

[WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/parenting/features/chores-for-children##1) lists  the following as age appropriate chores:

- Sort laundry
- Sweep floors
- Set and clear table
- Help make and pack lunch
- Weed and rake leaves
- Keep bedroom tidy

In addition to the chores they deem appropriate at earlier ages.

**Ages 4-5**

- Make their bed
- Empty wastebaskets
- Bring in mail or newspaper
- Clear table
- Pull weeds, if you have a garden
- Use hand-held vacuum to pick up crumbs
- Water flowers
- Unload utensils from dishwasher
- Wash plastic dishes at sink
- Fix bowl of cereal

**Ages 2-3**

- Put toys away
- Fill pet's food dish
- Put clothes in hamper
- Wipe up spills
- Dust
- Pile books and magazines

---

I have a 5 year old and an additional chore that we have been working on is folding laundry and sorting recycling.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is different for every family, and what works for your neighbor might not work for you guys and vice versa.  Parenting is a kind of learning that experience can produce best.

I would make a list of everything that needs to be done in the family.  Everything from Budget and bills to putting away toys and making the beds.  Organize the list from most mature to least mature and then divide it all up in the way that makes the most sense for you and your family.  Your kids won't harbor bitterness or resent you for telling them to do the dishes before Dr. Phil says it's appropriate.  And, it's okay to say, "You know what? This isn't working, so as a family we want to make this work.  Let's try something new.  Anybody have an idea?"  Openness and transparency has served my wife and I well in these kinds of areas.